# Do I need to free any memory associated with parameter jobjectArray?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I have a method with following JNI method

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_android_Coordinates_Updates
(
JNIEnv * env,
jobject obj,
jobjectArray coordinates
)
    {
    int size = env->GetArrayLength(coordinates);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i ++)
        {
        jfloatArray row = (jfloatArray)env->GetObjectArrayElement(coordinates, i);
        jfloat *elements = env->GetFloatArrayElements(row , 0);

        //Do I need to release this or any other memory?
        env->ReleaseFloatArrayElements( row , (jfloat *)elements, i);
        }  
    }
```

My question is do I need to release any memory in this case?

I am asking this question because I have an Android app that passes small data(touch coordinates) with a fast pace from Java to JNI. When I move two fingers over my android device in fast speed, app crashes in under 15 seconds. I tried to narrow down the problem and came to the point where if I include line given below in method above app crashes, otherwise it doesn't.

```
jfloat *elements = env->GetFloatArrayElements(row , 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You need to call ReleaseXxxxArrayElement() when you have used GetXxxxArrayElements() to undo the work.

```
// why did you use "i" ?
env->ReleaseFloatArrayElements( row , (jfloat *)elements, 0);
// we cleanup local ref due to looping ("size" might be large!)
env->DeleteLocalRef(row);
```

Do you have an array of an array ?  My guess below is what application code might looks like based on what I see in your problem, please modify it repost into the question.

```
Float[] firstElement = new Float[2];
firstElement[0] = 1.0f;   // x value 
firstElement[1] = 42.0f;  // y value

Object[] coordinates = new Object[1];
coordinates[0] = firstElement;

com.android.Coordinates coordObject = new com.android.Coordinates();
coordObject.Updates(coordinates);
```

Comment: Yes, I have an array of arrays passed through Java into JNI and that's why I have used i i.e. to get each array one by one

Comment: Thanks it worked. Can you tell me what is the last parameter of ReleaseFloatArrayElements?

Comment: It is down as a "jint mode" but what is actually means I don't know.  It is certainly not an index.  You should check for 0 returns and also check the length env->GetArrayLength(row) before accessing "elements[0]" maybe your example cut out those parts of your real project.

Comment: [The meaning of `mode` is documented here.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17454)